# High CPU Usage Sql Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have in-memory table in Azure Sql where there are high volume of insertion on it could reach 7000/sec, so far it consume high CPU up to 90%. could any one explain why and how can I improve it?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTransactions]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Points] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeviceId] [char](36) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [TransactionTypeId] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ActionBy] [int] NOT NULL,

INDEX [idx_hash_UserTransactions_UserId] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [UserId]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 524288),
 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
),
INDEX [UserTransactionsUIX_NonClustered] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [ActionBy],
    [TransactionTypeId]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 262144)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA )
```

---

```
    SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) from UserTransactions 
where ActionBy=@IBidId and TransactionTypeId=@TId
```

---

```
SELECT @UserPoints = isnull(sum(points),0) FROM UserTransactions WHERE userid = @IUserId
```

Comment: what is your pricing tier

Comment: Can you look at sys.dm_db_wait_stats to understand what is causing the database to run slowly? That will tell us more than just a table definition.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, p4

Comment: @GrantFritchey, what should I look for in it?

Comment: Capture the information before running the query and after running the query. You'll see exactly what is causing things to run slow based on the waits. That will tell you if it's memory, cpu or disk, plus it'll narrow down the specifics based on the wait type.

Comment: @GrantFritchey, I did run it before and after but without any difference.

select * from sys.dm_db_wait_stats;
SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) from UserTransactions where ActionBy=5642 and TransactionTypeId=9;
select * from sys.dm_db_wait_stats;

Comment: Any differences at all are what you're looking for. Running this won't make the query run faster. It identifies what the query is waiting on.